# How can I stream a video as the same position to all viewers?

Tags: video, stream, live-streaming

I would like to stream a video on my website, such that all people visiting he site will start watching at the same position in the video (as though it's a live feed, although it will just be a static avi). Is it possible to do this? I've found stuff to stream a video normally but not sure how to ensure everyone will be watch the same position in the video at the same time.

Some extra detail: My rational for wanting to do this is to save bandwidth by streaming a single video to anyone watching, instead of each viewer starting a separate stream from the beginning. Does that make sense or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [IP multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) but its deploy it's problematic and the ISPs of your user must support it.

Realistically, you should use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).